# Changing HiddenField value in codebehind no changing in Javascript function in order to use showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, hiddenfield

In my  Vb .net code-behind (Visual Studio 2005), in a method fired by click event:

hdnUrl and hdnParameters are hiddenFields

```
Protected Sub btnExample_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExample.Click
.
.
.
hdnUrl.Value = "Mypage.aspx?i=" & SomeCveDefinedInCodeBehind.Tostring & "&u=" & OtherCveDefinedInCodeBehind.Tostring
hdnParameters.value = "resizable: no; scroll: no; center: yes; dialogHeight: 525px; dialogWidth:750px; status: no;"

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType, DateTime.Now.ToString, "<script type='text/javascript'> ShowWindow(); </script>", False)

.
.
.
```

In my page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph3" runat="Server">
.
.
.
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUrl" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnParameters" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResult" runat="server" Value="" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ShowWindow()
    {

      alert('i am here');

      var url = document.getElementById('<%= hdnUrl.ClientID %>').value;
      var Parameters = document.getElementById('<%= hdnParameters.ClientID %>').value;

      //For test:      
      alert(url);  //------ i need to get here: "My page.aspx?...", but i always get: ""
      alert(parameters); // i need to get here my parameters,   but i always get: ""
      .
      .
      .

      var dialogWin = window.showModalDialog(url, "some text", parameters);  //showModalDialog window, will return a data that i need in CodeBehind 
      document.getElementById('<%= hdnResult.ClientID %>').value=dialogWin.result;
      //Then i could manage the result, in code-behind      
    }

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Only if in the hidden field definition i set:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUrl" runat="server" Value="My text" />
```

i can get this text in the javascript alert, but i need define the text in code-behind

Thanks for your Help and suggestions.
is there another way for pass url and parameters, to the window.showModalDialog???
or another way for get the result of the window.showModalDialog in code.behind???

Comment: Rats. I am here now for the exact same reason.

Comment: From what I'm finding, client side script can't execute in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the casing on your Parameters variable. Also try using RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock. The difference is the former will put your javascript at the bottom of the page while the latter puts it at the top. This will cause the script to run before the document it fully loaded.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, DateTime.Now.ToString, "<script type='text/javascript'> ShowWindow(); </script>", False)
```